# How to select the schema I want from a Postgresql database?

Tags: php, postgresql

I have two schemas, one called public and another called SIEM.
I want to print a table from the SIEM schema, but it is not printing anything.
How can I select the schema I want to print a table from?

```
$query = "SELECT * from Maquina222";

$result = pg_query($conn,$query);

$i = 0;
echo '<html><body><table><tr>';
while ($i < pg_num_fields($result))
{ 
   $fieldName = pg_field_name($result, $i); 
   echo '<td>' . $fieldName . '</td>'; 
   $i = $i + 1;
}
echo '</tr>';

$i = 0;

while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) 
{ 
    echo '<tr>'; 

    $count = count($row); 
    $y = 0;
    while ($y < $count)
    { 
        $c_row = current($row);
        echo '<td>' . $c_row . '</td>';
        next($row);
        $y = $y + 1;
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    $i = $i + 1;
}
pg_free_result($result);

echo '</table></body></html>';
```

Answer (score 1):

you can either qualify the name of your table (`SIEM.Maquina222`) or add the schema to your *path* (`SET search_path = public,SIEM`).

edit:

see esp. [5.7.3. The Schema Search Path](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH).  you may want to use [ALTER TABLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdatabase.html) or [ALTER ROLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterrole.html).

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'add schema to PATH? Do you mean adding SET search_path = public,SIEM to my php code?